# What's the Parallel (virtual Machine) alternative for windows 8.1

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtual-machine

I'm trying to run Ubuntu 15 in virtual machine on Windows 8.1, I had experience with **Parallel** on mac it work perfectly so I'm looking for its alternative if it's possible on windows.
Any Ideas?

Comment: Please do not ask for *best*, that does not exist. Read http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information, [edit] your question and put in a list of requirements. As it is now, we could recommend *any* VM.

Comment: You might consider VMware, but I strongly prefer [VirtualBox][1], from Sun, which is free.

AFAIK, it is the leader in such programs. Certainly most companies which I have worked at use it and I have used it happily for years at home.

You can create your own VM from an ISO, or download one from [here][2].


  [1]: https://www.virtualbox.org/
  [2]: https://virtualboximages.com/veedeeeyes/vdi/index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle makes [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and there's also [VMWare](http://www.vmware.com/) in the marketplace.

Both of them work pretty well in my experience, though I've used VirtualBox more recently.